# Windows 10 no IPv6 RA after suspend

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, ipv6

I have noticed that a Windows 10 client sometimes does not get an IPv6 address on my network. Looking in to this I have discovered it is limited to resume after suspend. Running wireshark on the client I can see the router solicitation go out but no router advertisement is received, either periodically or in response to the solicitation. While disconnecting from the wireless network and reconnecting does not solve the problem, disabling and re-enabling the wireless NIC does solve the problem and RAs are once again received. While this is a workaround solves the problem it is not a good long term solution.

I have been trying to research this problem, but Windows 10 IPv6 resources seem to be virtually non existent or at best only scratch the surface and I do not know how to further troubleshoot the problem. I should add that my NIC driver is up to date.

How can I find the root cause of this problem to eliminate the issue once and for all?

Comment: Wild guess: Sounds like a driver error, where after resume the driver doesn't register all MAC address it wants to receive packets for.

Comment: That's my gut feeling as well. Any tips on how I should report this to the manufacturer (dell)?

Comment: I think creating a support case would be the first step, assuming the PC is still covered under a support contract. In any case please post exact details about the system that you are seeing this on. It might help others with the same problem, and it might even trigger some Dell people into looking into this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell have confirmed it is a bug. The workaround is to disable power management on the card. Driver version I was using is 1.566.0.0 for "Dell Wireless 1830 802.11ac" card.

Comment: I'm seeing an issue that is virtually identical (IPv6 address lost shortly after standby, ICMPv6 RA packets not coming through, disabling/enabling Wifi adapter solves the issue) on an Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX210.